# Migrate web2py application from fullcalendar 3.4.0 to version 4

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler, web2py

I have an application written in web2py using fullcalendar scheduler (licensed) 3.4.0.

I don't know what actions I need to do to:

- install new fullcalendar framework on my application
- how to "adapt" the application to the new framework

I don't understand if I can use jQuery or not in the new framework...

I'd like to have like a guide to do this step-by-step..
Thank you

Comment: I don't see why anything would prevent you from using jQuery. It still works on web pages. fullCalendar 4 doesn't require it itself anymore, but that doesn't stop you from using it anywhere else you want to in your page.

Comment: The rest of your question is not really answerable since we don't know anything about your current setup